# How to i compare two lists of different types in Java?

Tags: java, list, compare

I have two lists:

The first list is a list of MyObject which contains an int and a String:

```
List<MyObject> myObjList = new ArrayList<>();

myObjList.add(new MyObject(1, "Frank"));
myObjList.add(new MyObject(2, "Bob"));
myObjList.add(new MyObject(3, "Nick"));
myObjList.add(new MyObject(4, "Brian"));
```

The second list is simply a list of strings:

```
List<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    
personList.add("Nick");
```

I want to compare the list of strings (***personList***) with string in the list of MyObject (***myObjectList***) and return a list of id's with all the matches. So in the examle it should return a list containing only Nicks id -> 3. How do I do that?

UPDATE:

To get a list of id's I simply said:

```
myObjectList.stream()
.filter(mo -> personList.contains(mo.id))
.map(MyObject::id)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: For your update: reverse the map and filter, then the filter can simply be: `.filter(personList::contains)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear which way round you want, but if you want the elements in `personList` which are ids of elements in `myObjList`:

```
personList.stream()
    .filter(s -> myObjList.stream().anyMatch(mo -> mo.id.equals(s)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or, if you want the elements in `myObjList` whose ids are in `personList`:

```
myObjectList.stream()
    .filter(mo -> personList.contains(mo.id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(In the latter case, it may be better for `personList` to be a `Set<String>`).